# Can't login with Nautilus SFTP

Tags: ssh, nautilus, sftp

I can't login with Nautilus SFTP to a server on my local network.

I only get the message:

(Norwegian) "Oops! Något gick fel.Har inte nödvändiga rättigheter för att komma åt den begärda platsen."

> Oops! Something went wrong. Don't have permission to access the requested location.

With Bash I can login with SSH and SFTP without any problems and in Nautilus this worked earlier without a glitch.
What has gone wrong and what can I do?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I could replicate the error trying to access to a folder that it's not owned by the user you login with. 1) Can you login to you_user@the_ip? 2) If yes, does this user have privileges to access the location you are going?

Comment: Usually this means you need to execute: `ssh-add` to make your ssh-agent aware of your ssh keys. Of course, you first need to try to use `ssh` command to validate that you can successfully connect there manually, to rule out other issues.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, but it turned out that there was a problem on the server. Removal and re-installation of open-ssh on the server solved the problem.
H

Comment: Please delete the question.